# Store Scope in JSON

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am working on a web app that displays a prompt based on which field the user has in focus or not. I have a few different scripts of text that I want to display at these different points.

What I would like to do is display the scope data in those strings when they are displayed. Right now everything gets rendered as text. Here is what I am doing. In the view. (Ignore my poor use of ng-init I will change this to a controller.)

```
    <div><p>Full Name</p><input placeholder="Name" name="personal.name" ng-model="personal.name" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'default blur' }" class="medium" type="text"/></div>
    <div><p>Address</p><input class="long" type="text" ng-model="personal.address" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'default blur' }" placeholder="Address"/></div>
    <div><p>Phone</p><input placeholder="Phone" ng-model="personal.phone" type="phone" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'default blur' }" only-digits/></div>

        <div ng-init="script()">
         <div ng-repeat="scripts in script">
          <div ng-show="{{scripts.element}}" ng-hide="true" class="alert-bar">
            <div class="wrapper">
              <div ng-bind="scripts.script"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
```

and the controller again ignore the data in this I will store this later.

```
    $scope.script = function(){

          $scope.script = [
            {
             'element': "personal.name",
             'script': '{{personal.name}} welcome to SOCU\'s loan application.'
            },
            {
             'element': "personal.address",
             'script':  '{{personal.name}}, please enter your full current address.'
            },
            {
             'element': "personal.phone",
             'script': '{{personal.name}}, please enter your current phone number, with the area code.'
            }
          ];
    }
```

Everything works except I cannot get the name to show up. I know that I shouldn't use the double curly brackets here.  I've also tried getting the data directly from the $scope but I don't see any personal data there.

Comment: Are you going to ng-repeat the script array?

Comment: Yep that is what I'm doing. Which that works.

Comment: Does my answer make sense?

Comment: I think I am doing what you are suggesting. I don't see how to access the personal object data though.

Comment: I will give you the edited post

Comment: Please find my edited post with a code

Comment: I just included your actual code. Let me know if that works.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do bindings in your controller as they are dedicated to view only.

Since you iterate the script array you can just access the elements of object by,

```
{{scripts.element + scripts.script}}
```

Handlebar syntax should work for div element. Have an array structure as given below,

```
$scope.script = [{
    element: 'Person name',
    script: 'Your script'
}];
```

In your div,

```
<div ng-init="script()">
    <div ng-repeat="scripts in script">
        <div ng-show="{{scripts.element}}" ng-hide="true" class="alert-bar">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div>
                    {{ scripts.element + " , " + scripts.script }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am binding to the scripts in the div.